# How do I get the CSS width value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

I'm trying to calculate the width of an element so that when I use JavaScript to wrap a parent element around it, I can set the width of the parent to match the width of the child.  The obvious `$('#element').css('width');` isn't quite what I want because it only seems to return the calculated value in pixels.  Is there some way that I can return the actual CSS value, whether it be `300px` or `20%` or `auto`, instead of the calculated value?

Here's generally how it's set up, but I'd like to know the CSS value of `#child` instead of the calculated value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#child').wrap('<div id="parent"></div>');
    $('#parent').each(function(){
        var childWidth = $(this).children('#child').css('width');
        $(this).css('width', childWidth)
    });
});
```

Comment: There was a very closely related question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105355 Read @bobince's answer for some background

Comment: Do you want to get the width property of the `style` attribute on the element, or also settings defined in CSS classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that. The best you will get is offsetWidth or clientWidth which return the calculated value, with and without counting margins, padding and borders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the stylesheet itself.

See: [How can I read out the CSS text via Javascript as defined in the stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031347/how-can-i-read-out-the-css-text-via-javascript-as-defined-in-the-stylesheet)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone but IE supports `window.getComputedStyle(element)`, which you can use like so:

```
getComputedStyle($('#child')).width; // returns actual width of #child
```

Doesn't help you with IE, though.

Comment: Piss. The whole reason I was doing this was so that I could put a blur filter on the parent element "if lte IE 8" to mimic the CSS3 box-shadow look (see: http://martinsmucker.com/demo/ie_shadow2.html). :-/  This is a very helpful thing to know, though, thanks!

Comment: This is also in pixels, not actual CSS value if is 100% for example